# How to show you save next to price in woocommerce single product page

Tags: woocommerce

Please developers tell me How to show you save next to price in woocommerce single product page. same like screenshot. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/gKiYc.png)

Answer (score 0):

```
function show_you_save(){

global $product;
  
   if( $product->is_type('simple') || $product->is_type('external') || $product->is_type('grouped') ) {
      
         $regular_price     = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_regular_price', true ); 
        $sale_price     = get_post_meta( $product->get_id(), '_sale_price', true );
     
         if( !empty($sale_price) ) {
  
              $amount_saved = $regular_price - $sale_price;
              $currency_symbol = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
              $percentage = round( ( ( $regular_price - $sale_price ) / $regular_price ) * 100 );
              ?>
              <p style="font-size:24px;color:red;"><b>You Save: <?php echo get_woocommerce_currency_symbol(); echo number_format($amount_saved,2, '.', '')." (". number_format($percentage,0, '', '')."%)"; ?></b></p>                        
              <?php        
        }
   }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'show_you_save', 11 );
```

Tested & works. You can change position of it as per your theme.

Comment: it's not work. it's show critical error in my site.

Comment: Hey, apologies. While formatting the code, part of it is gone. I have updated the code. Please check now.